# The notion of free algebra functor

Tags: category-theory

I am new in the category theory. According to the definition of functor, a ***functor*** is a type of mapping between categories arising in category theory. Functors can be thought of as homomorphisms between categories. During studying the notion of ***Algebraic Operad*** we have the following definition:

Given a type of algebras the algebraic operad is given by the functor
free algebra, which is a monad in Vect. If the relations are multilinear, then the endofunctor is a Schur functor.

What is the meaning of the functor free algebra in the above definition?

Comment: I presume, they mean the [tensor algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra) construction, which would be a functor $F\text{-Vec} → F\text{-Alg}$ that may be interpreted as a functor $F\text{-Vec} → F\text{-Vec}$ (where $F$ is the base field) by forgetting the multiplicative structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a category of algebraic objects $C$, such as groups, rings, modules, etc., equipped with the forgetful functor $U : C \to \text{Set}$ sending each object to its underlying set, the free algebra functor is the [left adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) of $U$; this means that there is a natural isomorphism

$$\text{Hom}_C(F(S), X) \cong \text{Hom}_{\text{Set}}(S, U(X))$$

for all $S \in \text{Set}, X \in C$. For groups this is the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) functor, etc.

$U$ and $F$ together give rise to a functor $M = U \circ F : \text{Set} \to \text{Set}$ which has the structure of a [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)). For algebraic objects the adjunction above is typically [monadic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadic+adjunction), meaning $C$ can be recovered from $M$ in a particularly nice way; in this case $M$ encodes the algebraic theory describing the objects of $C$.

If $C$ consists of algebras of some sort over vector spaces (e.g. algebras, commutative algebras, Lie algebras) then we can instead consider a forgetful functor $U : C \to \text{Vect}$ to vector spaces and a corresponding left adjoint $F : \text{Vect} \to C$. If $C$ is particularly nice it can be described by an [operad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory) $O$, in which case the induced monad $M = U \circ F : \text{Vect} \to \text{Vect}$ takes the form

$$M(V) = \bigoplus_{n \ge 0} O_n \otimes_{S_n} V^{\otimes n}$$

for some sequence of vector spaces with $S_n$-action $O_n$ making up the operad $O$. Functors of this form are sometimes called Schur functors, although that term is also sometimes reserved for special cases.

There's a lot of material implicit in these two sentences, and especially if you're new to category theory it could be awhile before you can fully understand them.

Comment: Very nice description of the concepts. But I agree that given the description of a functor as the OP gives in the question, they are probably jumping the gun somewhat if they are already trying to study operads.

Comment: Thank you so much for this nice explanation.